# How capture first occurrence of predefined input using regexp?

Tags: regex

I am learning regexp.my regexp is:

```
/^([0-5][0-9]|60):/g
```

My sample data is: `60:40:60 Lua`

Everything is fine. Now I want to extract first occurrence before :. i.e: 60 but when I try to using $1. it return `6040`. Any idea?

Comment: Can you share your code using the $1? [Testing you regex](https://regex101.com/r/TzYlgu/1), the first group contains 60.

Comment: I am trying to test code at : https://regexr.com/

Comment: Are you testing it [like this](https://regexr.com/3iku4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about that one:

```
^(?:[0-5][0-9]|60)(?=:)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KTmv7Z/5/)

Or in your way with validation, you may try that:

```
^(?:[0-5][0-9]|60)(?=:\d{2}:\d{2}.*)
```

Explanation:

1. `^(?:[0-5][0-9]|60)` - Same as yours
2. `(?=:\d{2}:\d{2}.*)`  -- positive lookahead to ensure that the previous  pattern is followed by 2 digit colon 2 digt and followed by rest of the string of zero or more length.

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/KTmv7Z/4/)

As it seems like it is not serving according to your need there is a solution that captures 3 groups where group 1 starts with the digits you desire:

```js
const regex = /^([0-5][0-9]|60):([0-5][0-9]|60):([0-5][0-9]|60).*$/gm;
const str = `60:40:60 Lua`;
let m;

if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
console.log(m[1]);
console.log(m[2]);
console.log(m[3]);
}
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but this doesn't really address what might be wrong with the OP's attempt.

Comment: @tripleee if you look at the code snippet in my answer in the bottom and match that with the op's quote "Now I want to extract first occurrence before :. i.e: 60 but when I try to using $1. it return 6040. Any idea? " then would you plz shed light on what is he trying to address ??? the language is not set....

Comment: Right, which is why I'm asking in which language the code you posted in your answer is written. I really can't tell.

Comment: this is plain javascript

Comment: Thanks. Hadn't seen backticks in Javascript before but that probably only reveals my ignorance. Maybe update the answer to mention this.